Nginx Reverse Proxy and CSS/JS Elements Not Showing
I have searched through this site and found similar questions to mine, but I haven't found something quite like my setup. I have a domain hosted on mysite.com. I want to proxy this domain to display content hosted on example.com/mysite. My current setup is properly proxying example.com/mysite, but CSS files, fonts, and other script elements that are hosted in another directory on example.com are not displaying. These files are attempting to load from mysite.com/test.css instead of where the files are actually located (example.com/test.css), so Network Inspector in Chrome is showing 404 errors when attempting to load the files.
In the HTML, the links to these files are relative references (a href='/test.css'). I was hoping to avoid the use of redirect rules since I want to preserve mysite.com in the address bar, and I didn't want to use sub filters since that seems costly on my web server. I also don't want to manually create individual location calls for each specific subdirectory.
Is there anything I can do to properly load the other site elements?
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name mysite.com;

  ssl_certificate /some/path/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /some/path/privkey.pem;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /some/path/chain.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://example.com/mysite;
    proxy_set_header Host example.com;

    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
  }
}

Thank you!

I had a similar issue, but different setup.
Try adding "rewrite ^/mysite/(.*)$ /$1 break;" in your location and see if that works out for you.

Thanks @KenjiBailly, but that didn't seem to have any effect when inserting it within the location block either before or after proxy_pass.

I'm not sure if this would work either, but it's worth a try.
There's a tag in html which let's you change the base path and has effect on how you load your resources.
<base href="https://example.com/mysite/"> put this in your head tag

Unfortunately, I don't have the ability to modify the HTML on the example.com site.

It seems that your website is not only hosted under //example.com/mysite/, as some of the files are hosted at //example.com/. To access all these files from one location, you need to use proxy_pass https://example.com; - maybe the simplest solution is to forward visitors to the correct URL, for example, add: location = / { return 301 /mysite/; }

That doesn't seem to work... it just returns mysite.com/mysite.

Add this below your current location block. You are redirecting to https://exmaple.com/mysite which completely ignores everything in the directory below (/). You need to add another location block that proxies the CSS separately.
location ~ \.css {
    proxy_pass https://example.com;
    proxy_set_header Host example.com;

    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
    # add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
}


Yes, this makes sense. However, is there a way to proxy everything via wildcard (with Regex) to avoid having to define other file extensions or directories explicitly?

@webman4224 not that I know of, but you can do something like this: location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js)$ {
